# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 argument, 8 given

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, pdo

Regresé a programar con PHP y estoy realizando distintas aplicaciones que son CRUD consecutivos, en estos momentos me encuentro realizando el formulario para la actualización de datos ("UPDATE") al momento de querer actualizar los datos me genera este error:

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 argument, 8 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sist\actualizar_usuario.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Sist\actualizar_usuario.php(18): PDOStatement->execute('', '152095', 'Usuario De Prueba', 'usarioE@pruebas.com', 'Pruebas', 'Update', 'Ciudad', 'Baja') #1 {main}

Este es el código que me marca el error:

```
<?php 
  print_r($_POST);

  include 'conexion.php';
  $id2=$_POST['id2'] ??"";
  $nom2=$_POST['txtNomina1'] ??"";
  $usserr2=$_POST['txtUsuario1'] ?? "";
  $mail2=$_POST['txtCorreo1'] ?? "";
  $puestoP2=$_POST['txtPuesto1'] ??"";
  $depar2=$_POST['txtDepartamento1'] ?? "";
  $sucur2=$_POST['txtSucursal1'] ?? "";
  $sUsuario2=$_POST['txtStatUssr1'] ??"";

$sentencia = $bd->prepare("UPDATE employees SET nomina = ?, nomUsuario = ?, correo = ?, 
                        puesto = ?, departamento = ?, sucursal = ?, estatus_usr = ? WHERE id_usuario =?;");


 $resultado = $sentencia->execute($id2,$nom2,$usserr2,$mail2,$puestoP2,$depar2, $sucur2, $sUsuario2);

  if ($resultado === TRUE) {
    header('Location: tabla_usuario.php');
  }else{
    echo "Error en la sentencia";
  }
?>
```

Este es el orden en mi base de datos:

id_usuario|nomina|
nomUsuario|
correo|
puesto|
departamento|
sucursal|
estatus_usr|

Este es mi código de la conexión:

```
<?php 
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $nombrebd="sae_jsg";

    try{
$bd=new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;
    dbname='.$nombrebd,
    $user,
    $pass,
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
    }
catch (Exception $e){
echo "Error de conexión".$e->getMessage();
}
 ?>
```

Recuerdo que se tenía que actualizar de manera individual, pero no se si sea esto así, agradecería cualquier ayuda y al igual si podrían usar un poco de código para entender el error o hacer la corrección sería de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el método [execute de PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php) requiere un array, de esta forma:

```
$resultado = $sentencia->execute(array($id2,$nom2,$usserr2,$mail2,$puestoP2,$depar2, $sucur2, $sUsuario2));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias vicent, agregue el código y funciono a la perfección